# I want to form a set of new matrices from a matrix which varies with time

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, matrix

I have a data matrix called `xnt` of size `16*96`. I break this data into overlapping windows as follows:

```
WL = 4;
for t = 4:96
    X_time_Total(:,:,t) = xnt(:,[(t-WL+1):t]);
end
```

Now I have `X_time_Total` which is a `16*4*96` matrix.

---

Next I form a new `16*16*93` matrix `Four_Xt`, which combines every four consecutive windows formed previously:

```
for tt = WL:93
    Four_Xt(:,:,tt)=[X_time_Total(:,:,tt),X_time_Total(:,:,tt+1),X_time_Total(:,:,tt+2),X_time_Total(:,:,tt+3)];
end
```

The first row of this `Four_Xt(:,:,tt)` is vector form of the first `4*4` matrix `ujTt`, the second row forms the second one of wanted `4*4` matrix `ujTt`. There are 16 rows in `Four_Xt(:,:,tt)`, so I have 16 `ujTt`s each of size 4*4 (For one istant of time `tt`).

---

**The problem is**: I want a new `4*4*16` matrix called `U`, for each time `tt:WL,...`.

For `j = 1:16` the `4*4` matrix layers are formed from `Four_Xt` as follows:

```
    ujTt(:,:,j)=[Four_Xt(j,tt-WL+1:tt);
                 Four_Xt(j,tt-WL+2:tt+1);
                 Four_Xt(j,tt-WL+3:tt+2);
                 Four_Xt(j,tt-WL+4:tt+3)];
```

`ujTt` must change with time because `Four_Xt` changes with time. How can I have `ujTt` for all times `tt` and all `j=1:16`?

---

I wrote the following for this but it's not correct.

```
ujTt_temp=[];
for tt=WL:93
    for j=1:N
        ujTt(:,:,j)=[Four_Xt(j,tt-WL+1:tt);Four_Xt(j,tt-WL+2:tt+1);Four_Xt(j,tt-WL+3:tt+2);Four_Xt(j,tt-WL+4:tt+3)];

        ujTt_temp(:,:,tt) = ujTt(:,:,j);                 
    end
    ujTt_all=[ujTt_temp;ujTt_temp];
end
```

It's a little bit confusing at least for me. I appreciate any help.

Comment: I think this is a little bit confusing for everyone, not just you! Try explaining what you are trying to achieve without your code etc. I get that you've made the overlapping windows, past that it's unclear what you're trying to do, let alone how to do it...

Comment: I think you need to have a good read of the [`reshape` documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you arrive at a point where you have a `16*16*93` matrix of all your data, and you want to split each of the 16 rows into a `4*4` matrix? You can turn it into a `4*4*16*93` matrix using [`reshape`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html):

```
U = reshape(Four_Xt, 4, 4, 16, 93);
```

Then you have 93 matrices of size `4*4*16` which are indexed using

```
t = 27;            % 27th sub-matrix;
ujTt = U(:,:,:,t); % 4*4*16 matrix
```

Comment: I was unaware of 4-D arrays. So this helps. Thank you.

Comment: You can make any dimensional arrays, as long as your computer has the memory to hold all of the elements! In this case, the number of elements is the same as your 3D array, so no troubles.